# JQuery Getting Value of Input Box in On Click Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

There's a lot of other threads on this topic but none of them solve my issue. I'm trying to get the value from a input field which I just inserted.  I insert my input box using this line of javascript:

```
processName.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="ProcessNameChange" value="' + oldName + '" >';`
```

Then I try to access it using:

```
var newName = $(this).closest("#ProcessNameChange").val();
```

Both of these are wrapped in an event, a button click event.  Below is the entire function if you'd like all of it.  Also, if you have a better way of coding anything I wrote, feel free to share it.

```
$('.Edit').click(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("id") != "submitUpdate") {
                $(this).attr("id", "submitUpdate");
                $(this).text("Submit");
                var closestTR = $(this).closest("tr");
                var processName = closestTR.children()[2];
                var processDescription = closestTR.children()[3];
                var processID = closestTR.children()[4];
                var oldName = processName.innerHTML;
                var oldDesc = processDescription.innerHTML;
                processName.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="ProcessNameChange" value="' + oldName + '" >';
                processDescription.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="ProcessDescChange" value="' + oldDesc + '" > ';
                submitButtonClick();
            } else {
                var newName = $(this).closest("#ProcessNameChange").val(); 
                var newDesc = $(this).closest("#ProcessDescChange").val();
                var processID = $(this).closest("tr").children()[4];

            }
```

--> Related to Comments:
The HTML for the input box always stays as shown below:  It's all made via a repeater than modified with javascript.

```
<tr>
<td class="grid-main-detail"></td>
    <td>
        <input id="ProcessNameChange" type="text" value="PNameOld">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="ProcessDescChange" type="text" value="PDescOld">
    </td>
    <td>
    <td>3547556300824952452</td>
    <td>Me </td>
    <td>7/19/2013 2:32:48 PM</td>   
</tr>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Unless your .edit class is inside of your input which is not based on your js, closest is not gonna work. http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: @Huangism, the HTML never changes in the input box.  Once I insert it, it is always <input id="ProcessNameChange" type="text" value="ValueOfOldName"> - even after I change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the closest selector incorrectly

see this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Td6Wx/3/

```
<div class="test"></div>
<a href="#" class="test2">asdasdas</a>
```

closest() (http://api.jquery.com/closest) travels up through its ANCESTORS, in your case .Edit is not a child of the input so of course it will not work. If you post your html structure we can probably provide a correct solution

Comment: Thanks!  Also, this is relating to Blurfus's answer below.  If I add a 2nd instance of ProcessNameChange, it can't have the same ID so will javascript remain it or is it possible to insert it incorrect?

Comment: I use a class instead if you have more than 1, I don't see where .Edit is in your html, can you clarify please?

Answer (score 1):

One question: why are you accessing the value of the input like

```
var newName = $(this).closest("#ProcessNameChange").val();
```

instead of:

```
var newName = $("#ProcessNameChange").val();
```

?

Since the item is unique (by virtue of its `id` attribute), I do not see a need to use `.closest()` to get to it (and its value).

Do you really need to select the input field in such a way?

Comment: Since I add the value via javascript I was afraid the value may not be unique.  Is that true?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to get rid of `innerHTML` to stay focused on jQuery methods such as `.append()` and `$()` to create elements. Besides I suppose you are looking for `td` tr's children.

```
var oldName = processName.text();
var oldDesc = processDescription.text();
processName.append($('<input type="text" id="ProcessNameChange" value="' + oldName + '" >'));
processDescription.append($('<input type="text" id="ProcessDescChange" value="' + oldDesc + '" > '));
```

Hope this helps,

R.